problem of correspondence between scheduled shifts and actual shifts in ER DIAGRAM
the employee has a strong key. On the one hand I record the shift calendar of each employee ("shift calendar") and on the other hand I record the shifts that were actually carried out by the employee. Now if employee "X" has two shifts, one on Monday morning and the other on Tuesday morning, and let's assume that he arrives on Monday evening, when he arrives he is referring to the Monday morning shift where he arrived late or the Tuesday morning shift where he arrived anticipated? there is no correspondence between the scheduled shifts and the shifts carried out.
er diagram
How can I add a match without creating redundancy?
I thought about associating "shift calendar" with "actual shift" with a 1:1 association to keep track of the shifts performed and which scheduled shifts they refer to but I don't know if it would be the best choice.

It's difficult to answer this question without more info, but... as a guess: each shift on the calendar has an ID.  When the employee arrives, they select a calendar shift, which triggers the creation of an actual shift.  The association between the calendar shift and actual shift would be the shift ID.

@devlincarnate the scheduled shift is weak compared to the area, the primary key of the area is the name while the primary key of the scheduled shift is the date in combination with the name of the area (multiple employees can have the same scheduled shift).
on the other hand, the actual shifts are weak compared to the employee.
Now in this diagram that I have attached in the photo I know the shifts of all the employees and they are also the shifts that they actually carry out.
But my problem is: shift that was performed by the employee which scheduled shift does it refer to?

"But my problem is: shift that was performed by the employee which scheduled shift does it refer to?"  Maybe none.  What happens when an employee is scheduled for two shifts and works six shifts to cover for other employees calling in sick?

@GilbertLeBlanc and this situation is not managed but I believe that in that case the table of scheduled shifts should be directly modified and the corresponding actual shift should be obtained. But how can I have the corresponding scheduled shift of the shift actually performed (assuming there are all scheduled shifts)

I don't think you understand.  Scheduled shifts are the fantasy.  Worked shifts are the reality.  No one is going to adjust the scheduled shifts to match the worked shifts.  Scheduled shifts and worked shifts have no correlation.  None.  Zero.

The diagram is not as detailed as your description but overall seems OK.  As for the problem of correlating worked to scheduled shifts: either the workers themselves indicate which shift they are covering, or, if it's an automatic correlation you need, a business rule must be established: for example, that whichever the worked shift, it covers the earliest undone scheduled shift by that worker, which at least works re an accounting system.  --  If that is what you were asking, I might convert it to an answer (maybe with few more details).


How can I add a match without creating redundancy?

Forecasted (Calendar) Shifts and Actual Shifts are two different things in the real world, on that basis there is no redundancy - both sets of data represent something that probably has business value.  For example, you'll need both if you wanted to do analysis on forecasts vs actual (% of actual shifts that did not match forecasted, etc).

Employee to Forecasted Shift is many to many, assuming that more than one employee is allocated to a given forecasted shift.
Employee to Actual Shift is many to many, assuming that more than one employee participates in a given actual shift...
...However its possible that it's a 1-to-many relationship, where the Actual Shift table is really Employee Actual Shift table - more on this below.

The trick is in how forecasted shifts relate to actual ones, if at all.  For example:

An Actual shift could be nothing more than a record of what happened - i.e. there might not be any link between the actual and Forecasted shifts, apart from which employees were linked, and perhaps date/time ranges.
Assuming there is always a Forecast shift (e.g. the latest one if you are doing versioning), you could include a reference to the forecasted shift that led the employee to an actual shift; this leads to the Employee Actual Shift model:

[ ID | Employee ID | Forecasted Shift ID | Actual Shift Start Date/Time | Actual Shift End Date/Time ]
Where:

Employee to Employee Actual Shift is 1-to-many (an employee has many actual shifts, but an actual shift only refers to one employee.
Forecasted Shift ID to Employee Actual Shift is 1-to-1.

